# How to get differential equations from simscape system?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape, simmechanics

I have simmechanics model in simscape, I have imported it from solidworks design

I'm able to get linearized model using linmod and it is okay as any system in simulink

The problem here that I want to get the differential equations for that system, Is there any way to extract them?

Comment: [linmod](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/linmod.html) returns either the state-space matrices, or the numerator/denominator of the transfer function for the linearized model.  Are you looking for more that?

Comment: I need the system equations without linearization

Comment: That's not possible.  You'll need to resort to pen and paper to write them out,

Comment: Sad news, it is okay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: no, there is no built-in functionality.
The long answer: you'd have to parse the Simscape network, query the source equations (if the source code is visible). And stack these together. That's a pretty involved workflow.